# ReactJS How to restart my component, unmount it or alternatively use useEffect

Tags: reactjs

Here is my code

I am running a Spinner on progress.

When it is done, it shows a "Success" message.

I made component for Home and for StatusInfoIcon (Spinner).

How can I remount the StatusInfoIcon component after "Success" message? I want to run the action for different ID

Tried passing properties like childKey via props with a value from Math.Random() but it didn't reset the component State, so it was stuck at "Success" message.

Home component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { withOktaAuth } from '@okta/okta-react';

import SearchBar from "../SearchBar"
import StatusIcon from "../StatusIconInfo"

import APIClient from '../apiClient'

const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    marginTop: 30
  },
  paper: {
    padding: theme.spacing(2),
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
  },
});

class Home extends React.Component {
  state = {
    showstatus: false
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    const accessToken = await this.props.authService.getAccessToken()
    this.apiClient = new APIClient(accessToken);
  }



  removeUser = async (id) => {
    const uuid = await this.apiClient.removeUser(id); 
    console.log(uuid);
    this.setState({uuid: uuid});
  }
  
  onSearch = (event) => {
    const target = event.target;
    if (!target.value || target.length < 3) { return }
    if (event.which !== 13) { return }

   this.removeUser(target.value);
   this.setState({showstatus: true});
    
  }


  render() {
    const uuid = this.state.uuid;     
    return (
      <div className={styles.root}>
        <SearchBar onSearch={this.onSearch} />
    {this.state.showstatus?
    <StatusIcon uuid={uuid}>
    </StatusIcon>
        :
          <div></div>
    }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(withOktaAuth(Home));
```

StatusInfoIcon component

```
import React from 'react';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { withOktaAuth } from '@okta/okta-react';
import { CircularProgress } from '@material-ui/core';
import Fade from '@material-ui/core/Fade';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import APIClient from '../apiClient'

const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    marginTop: 30
  },
  paper: {
    padding: theme.spacing(2),
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
  },
  placeholder: {
    height: 40,
  },
});


class StatusIcon extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    
    super(props);
    this.logout = this.logout.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      uuid: this.props.uuid,
      status: "progress"
    }
  }

  async logout(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.authService.logout('/');
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.state.uuid)
    const accessToken = await this.props.authService.getAccessToken()
    this.apiClient = new APIClient(accessToken);
    this.intervalId = setInterval(() => this.loadData(this.props.uuid), 1000);
    this.loadData(this.props.uuid); // also load one immediately
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.intervalId);
  }

  

  loadData = async (uuid) => {
    const taskstatus = await this.apiClient.checkStatus(uuid);
    console.log(taskstatus);
    this.setState({status: taskstatus});
    if(taskstatus === 'success')
      clearInterval(this.intervalId);

  }

  render() {
    const classes = withStyles();

    return (
      <div>
      <div className={classes.placeholder}>
        {this.state.status === 'success' ?
    (
          <Typography>Success!</Typography>
                
        ) : (
          <Fade
            in={this.state.status === 'progress'}
            style={{
              transitionDelay: this.state.status === 'progress' ? '800ms' : '0ms',
            }}
            unmountOnExit
          >
            <CircularProgress />
          </Fade>
        )}
      </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(withOktaAuth(StatusIcon));
```

Heard that despite setInterval I can use useEffect(), but I don't know how to use it in my code.

Comment: React component will re-render whenever it's state value is changed. Or it's parent component is re-rendered. Are you sure, the state values are updating correctly ?

Comment: This I don't get about ReactJS. I stop my polling, so state will remain at "success" state. How can I remove my component now? I thought that Parent component will create new child component (Spinner) and there will be a fresh state, but it seems it holds the old "success" state (Success message is being displayed)

Comment: Or this cannot be done and my approach is wrong/anti pattern :)

Comment: Read about useEffect hook ... but don't know how to use it with those components. This is my first ReactJS code

Comment: useEffect is for functional react component. You are using react class component.

Comment: you want to remove the StatusIcon component after success message ?

Comment: Yes exactly. In Home component I get ID to remove and than it tracks the progress (Spinner). If I type new ID in Home it should fire Spinner for that ID. P.S I have to think of the way maybe to add a Spinner List so that old unfinnished jobs will also be tracked. But this is a bonus, extra thing to think about

Comment: I will post a simple code to handle communication between child to parent component communication

Comment: Thank you. Sweet. I am a newbie, so also other newbies will appreciate a somewhat full response. I noticed many questions on SO are partly coded. For a newbie, you cannot tell what is missing.

Comment: I am also open to other ideas/implementations. I want to get ID, process it, show spinner while doing, success on done. Next one should show new spinner in addition or replacement. If a replacement a disable on getting ID field could be nice, so user cannot create more than one concurrently.

Comment: I posted an example code. You can call a function in parent component from child component with required values

Comment: it is easy to do what you are asking in react. Hope you understand my example

Comment: feel free to comment any questions you have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer https://react-cn.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html

I am using simple code to explain communication between child and parent components using callback with React props. You can change it as required

```
class Home extends React.Component {
  state = {
    showstatus: false
  };

  //... other code in Home component ...//

  //function that will be called from StatusInfo component
  handleStatusChange(params) {
      //your logic here
  }


  //render method for example only to understand easily
  render() {
    const uuid = this.state.uuid;     
    return this.state.showstatus ?
        (<StatusIcon onStausChange={this.handleStatusChange.bind(this)} uuid={uuid}>
            </StatusIcon>)
        :
        (<div></div>);
  }
}
```

In above code I am passing a function from parent component to child component by the name `onStatusChange`. You can use any other names instead of `onStatusChange`

In child component, you can access this function using `this.props.onStatusChange`.

```
class StatusIcon extends React.Component {
  
  //...Code for StatusIcon component here ...//

  loadData = async (uuid) => {
    const taskstatus = await this.apiClient.checkStatus(uuid);
    console.log(taskstatus);
    this.setState({status: taskstatus});
    if(taskstatus === 'success') {
      clearInterval(this.intervalId);

      //Inform parent component about status change 
      //Pass all required details from StatusIcon to parent component here
      this.props.onStatusChange(taskstatus);
    }
  }

  //... render method ...//

}
```

Comment: Thank you! Works! However there is a small side effect that if I run in second time, the first request to CheckStatus goes to old ID UUID, continous requests are then with correct new ID UUID.

Comment: Code used: https://0bin.net/paste/p5++I2v0#E-yKeFuxjknvZZYGDlNtUKtDHWVGXIu6Kxv9keFx0EF

Comment: Sorry I saw this comment just now. Let me check

Comment: @dev UUID value is not initialized like showStatus. Maybe it's value is undefined during first time

Comment: It is actually on first request ever undefined, than on each attempt every n attempt has first request with uuid from previous one. Maybe some async, interval issue

Comment: Yes. I think that's the case. The components are rendering before a required asynchronous operation gets completed

Comment: Added undefined check in ApiClient and also removed "this.loadData(this.props.uuid); // also load one immediately" and this solved both issues. Seems it was too quick and had old props